How to use an image as a texture for SwiftUI MapKit MapPolygon
I'm trying to add an image to fill/use as a texture in a MapPolygon on my Map, however my image never shows up. Does anyone know how to use an image in a MapPolygon?
When I just use .foregroundStyle(.green) the green color shows up, but the image just won't show.
Here's my code:
Map(position: $camera, bounds: viewModel.camera) {

      MapPolygon(coordinates: coords).foregroundStyle(.image(Image(.img)).opacity(0.9))
   
                }


Map content doesn't support every kind of ShapeStyle. It also doesn't support materials, for example.
